# What should you call a whooping cough or a whoop-like cough and not have it confused with the disease?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

How would you tell someone that you have a whooping cough but you don't have pertussis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not talking about the disease then you're just describing the cough.

You could use a synonym for whoop:  clamor, howl, bark,

You could try a different description: a violent cough.

You could make a joke out of the confusion:  He had a cough that happens to whoop.  Not that there is anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

The noun *whoop* exists outside of any *whooping-cough* context. Whilst OED sense 1b deals with the sound made in whooping-cough, it makes clear that the term is also applied to similar sounds - with particular reference to the example from 1899.

> 1b. The characteristic sonorous inspiration following a fit of
>   coughing in whooping-cough. Also applied to similar sounds (see quot.
>   1899).
>
> 1873   A. Flint Treat. Princ. Med. (ed. 4) 240   A long and labored
>   inspiration then takes place, giving rise to a crowing sound evidently
>   due to spasm of the glottis; this is the whoop which enters into the
>   name of the affection.
>
> 1897   T. C. Allbutt et al. Syst. Med. II. 239   When the whoop
>   appears his power of communicating the disease begins to decline.
>
> **1899   T. C. Allbutt et al. Syst. Med. VII. 452   Occasionally the
>   impediment is aggravated by the occurrence of associated sounds with
>   the stutter, the patient emitting unpleasant little whoops, grunts, or
>   whimpering sounds during his efforts to speak.**